# Invoking Hibernate PostInsertEventListener after flush

Tags: hibernate, event-handling

I have a class implementing Hibernate `PostInsertEventListener` which is tied to the Hibernate `SessionFactory` via Spring. The interceptor is specified for `post-insert` event type . This interceptor gets invoked whenever I perform a `session.save(entity)`. However, the execution happens before the transaction is flushed. This is problematic if the database throws an exception.

**Question:**
Is there a way I can specify to invoke an interceptor **after** the `session.flush()` has been called?

I tried doing `insertEvent.getSession().flush()` within the event listener but that produces a primary key violation exception since the id was not yet set.

I have not yet explored the `registerSynchronization` way because it seems like I am missing some basic configuration. The transaction manager being used is `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager` and the transactional boundaries are specified by the `@Transactional` annotation. Hibernate version is 3.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Current solution:

Store the Post(Insert|Update|Delete)Event in a Map with Session as the key. Get the event from the map in the FlushEventListener for the Session and process the event.

The map used is a [Guava Cache](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained) with an expiration interval set to minutes. This will catch the case where the flush() fails because of a SQLException and the entry for that session needs to be removed from the map.

Answer (score 4):

you can use `post-commit-(update|delete|insert)` for listener type. it called after commit Transaction

Comment: Excellent, thanks for posting this answer. Couldn't find this information anywhere after trying to solve the same issue for hours. Works a treat!

Answer (score 1):

How about using a [FlushEventListener](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/event/FlushEventListener.html)?

Comment: I did that and it gets invoked but FlushEvent does not have any properties that I want to examine.

Comment: Just thought I'd mention it.

Comment: I had to couple the FlushEventListener with the Post(Insert|Update|Delete)Listener using a map. I am not sure if you were hinting at it. Thanks!